# Build target in the Publish Profile is not executing even if the Publish is successful

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task, visual-studio-2019

I have a publish profile `Staging.pubxml` created for a console project (.NET Core 2.1), as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <Configuration>Staging</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\</PublishDir>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>true</_IsPortable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CustomActionsAfterPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
    <Message Text="First occurrence" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

When I publish it (via VS2019); publish  completes successfully. Yet I'am not seeing the text: `First occurrence` in the output window.

In VS, MSBuild output verbosity is set to `Diagnostic`.

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I doing this wrong?

1.Hi friend, the .pubxml file is not a good place to define custom Target.

According to your target name, you want to run the target after build target. For this situation: always we define the custom target in project file. Please try `right-click your project` and choose `edit xxx.csproj`, and add the target into it. Then reload the project and publish, then you can find the `First occurrence` message in the build output.

And after my test, in.csproj file, the target can't be named AfterBuild, you can change it to:

```
 <Target Name="CustomTargetName" AfterTargets="build">
    <Message Text="First occurrence" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
```

2.Also, the way you use can work in VS2019 though we don't suggest adding it in .pubxml. But it indeed works. For the reason why you can't get the message in output window, please check if the Staging.pubxml is really called during the publish process.

[image]

(Change the value of the PublishDir to another folder, and publish it again, check if the project is published to new directory, then you'll find if the xxx.pubxml is used)

**Update:**

According to your .pubxml file, your project is a .net core **console app** instead of a **asp.net core web app**. This makes the difference!

I test it in both VS2017 and VS2019, and find the target works well in asp.net web app but not .net core console one. I believe for those non-web app, this kind of after publish target may not be supported.

And please check these two official documents I found:

Asp.net core: [Run a target before or after publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.1#run-a-target-before-or-after-publishing)

.net core: [Deploy .net core apps with VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs157)

I can't find any custom-target-related info in the .net core document. So I'm afraid it might be not supported by design.

**Update2:**

Actually your original need is to add CopyFiles target to publish process. So I assume what you really want is to `copy sth to Publish Folder after Publish` process or `copy sth from Publish Folder to target folder`.

Though the after publish target is not supported in .net core console apps. We have corresponding workarounds:

- To copy sth to Publish Folder after Publish:

For this situation, you can add a after build target to copy the files to Publish folder before publish process. I think it works for this situation:

```
<Target Name="CustomTarget" AfterTargets="build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MySourceFiles Include="xxx\pathToTheFolderWhereYourFilesAre\*.*"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy
          SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"
          DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\"
        />
  </Target>
```

- To copy sth from Publish Folder to target folder:

**For .net core console app, actually the so-called publish process is to copy files from obj folder to publish folder.** See this screenShot:

[image]

Go `Tools=>Options=>Project and Solutions=>Build and Run` to change the build output verbosity to Detailed and you can see details in build and publish process in VS.

That's why I suggest you can Go Project=>Properties=>build events=>post-build events to use a xcopy command to copy the files to your destination folder.(Or you can use a script like above, remember to change the source path and destination path). **When we want to copy the files in publish folder, actually we're trying to copy the files from obj folder.** So do something after build process is enough! Not need to do it after publish process.

Comment: thanks @Lance Li-MSFT.
 
On 1: my actual need is to add a `CopyFiles` target/task to the publish process. but that execute either, so this was a test to see if any other target would get execute.

On 2: i changed the PublishDir  in the `.pubxml` and it published to the new location - so yes, the correct `.pubxml` is being called during the publish process.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I even changed it to `<Target Name="CustomActionsAfterPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">` still the message is not logged in to output window

Comment: @dan Hi friend, please check if my update help describes this situation. And since the target in .pubxml for .net core deploy may not be supported, have you tried to use target in .csproj with AfterTarget element to achieve your goal. Since the deployed files are copied from obj to publish folder, so there is possibility you can use the target in .csproj to copy the files you want though the target is in .csproj not in .pubxml.

Comment: Hi friend, yes adding the target to the console .csproj worked liked a charm (A minor change i did - I used `PublishDir` macro instead of the `ProjectDir`.) thanks alot!

Comment: You can perfectly add this to the pubxml file... Actually it is even better because you can have different pubxml files for different environments.

Comment: For me this is unfulfilling. I have a case where I have two different publishing profiles and I need to execute a command only when one of the two is being published. I dislike this lack of consistency from Microsoft.

Comment: FYI that the AfterTargets="build" finally fixed my issue with a single file, self-contained NET 8 Console app.  Now I can add other commands like MakeDir.  Thanks.