# Add a new publish target to custom project template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, visual-studio-2019, vsixmanifest

[image]I want to add a new publish target for an extension I am working on. When you right click on a project, there is a publish button that shows up. When you click that the picture I attached shows up. I want to add 2 of my own publish target under Azure WebJobs. Does anyone have any code or guides on how I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you share the screenshot as an image in your post.

Comment: Choose the `Create Profile` instead of `Publish Immediately` option. Then it will create a .pubxml file for you. You can define your custom targets there. Spmething you want to do is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627173/build-target-in-publish-profile-is-not-executing-even-if-the-publish-is-successf), right? Have to say this behavior is not supported for all project types.

Comment: Also, one point to clarify, I don't think your project is [.vsix project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-the-vsix-project-template?view=vs-2019#deploy-a-custom-project-template-using-the-vsix-project-template), I never find a publish button for this kind of project.

Comment: Correct, but I want these publish targets to show up only in my extension.

Comment: In my extension, I am creating a custom project type. For that project type, I want these custom publish targets to show up. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: It could be complex. Right-click the project to see Publish button see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e98eda6-b732-4850-b71d-732420523f18/vs2012-addin-how-to-add-a-solution-explorer-context-menuitem). To show up or create a ToolWindow see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-and-customizing-tool-windows?view=vs-2019). But i'm not sure if it's supported to implement the Publish window.

Comment: Hi, I don't see any instructions on how to add the publish button in the first link you sent.

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extensibility-hello-world?view=vs-2019), and set the Parent node for Group Section as :`<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJNODE"/>`, then right-click project, you can find your custom command there.